# Pinterest API get statistic for URL

Tags: api, pinterest

I am trying to find a way to get statistic for the URL from Pinterest API.

Like facebook graph API: [URL Object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/url/)

Or linked in `countserv` endpoint:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?format=json&url=https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/breaking-5-major-boolean-syntax-changes-irina-shamaeva
```

I know it is possible because this site is returning the number of pins for given url:

https://www.sharedcount.com/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F

Does anyone know how to get these data from Pinterest API?

Answer (score 1):

There is no officially supported way to do this with the developer API. That said, the widgets use this for the count bubbles using this API

`https://widgets.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url=<url>`.

I wouldn't depend on it for anything important tho since it is unsupported and can change/be removed at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of pins calling this url

```
http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=&url=http://stylehatch.co
```

It will return an object like this:

```
({"count": 0, "url": "http://stylehatch.co"})
```